# Can rocket.chat be server on 2 interfaces at the same time?

Tags: dns, rocket.chat, caddyfile

here is the situation,

- we have a domain, let's say example.com
- I have added a subdomain to the dns, chat.example.com
- I have modified the Caddyfile inserting http://chat.example.com (it works fine)

However, rocket.chat is hosted on our local server, and it is behind the router provided by our ISP, which apparently is programmed to return its own home page if an address is typed that resolves to its external ip address. In other words, if a computer located inside our local network types http://chat.example.com, it gets the router home page (the one where you can configure it).

I have solved it by modifying the hosts file, but I would prefer a cleaner solution. Is there anything that I can do on the Caddyfile, perhaps allow him to reply on 2 interfaces (http://chat.example.com and http://192.168.1.x), or something else that I have not thought yet?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you modify your DNS and make chat.example.com resolve to 192.168.1.x?

Comment: @DusanBajic I was referring to the DNS of the website (so that can only be pointed to external IP addresses); however, you made me think, and I have installed the DNS role on the internal windows server. Any suggestion on how to configure it?

Comment: It shouldn't matter where or which DNS server are you using. If you managed to make chat.example.com resolve to your router's public IP address, you should be able to change it to internal chat ip address

Comment: @DusanBajic Well, I cannot setup the DNS on the domain provider to point to 192.168.x.x because it is an local address. I can only set it to point to the external one.

Comment: That is one strange DNS provider :), I can't help you further (I am completely unfamiliar with Caddy) but it should certainly be doable to configure it to respond to http://192.168.1.x)

Comment: @DusanBajic Thank you in any case!